# Which is the area of intersection, using polar coordinate

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

For the curves $r=3cos\theta$ and $r=1+\cos\theta$ i need to find the area on the intersection of two curves. Now, $3cos\theta=1+\cos\theta$ implies that $cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ which said that $\theta=-+\frac{\pi}{3}$. By formula i know that

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int r^2 d\theta$$

My problem is how can set the limits looking my draw. I am not sure if the first integral need to be between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$ using the function $r=1+\cos\theta$ and my second integral would be between $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\pi$ but using another function $r=3\cos\theta$? Then sum the two integral and finally multiply by $2$ by symmetry in the graph?  Please, can somebody give me a hint or tell me if as I said,  it is correct?

In summary, is correct say that
$$A=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(1+\cos\theta)^2d\theta +  \frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi}(3\cos\theta)^2d\theta \right)?$$

Thank you

[image]

Comment: The drawing is very hard to follow. Easier to do is to use symmetry about the polar axis and find the area on the interval $[0, \pi/3]$ and multiply by 2 at the end.

Comment: Hint: In plain coordinates, how would you find the area between $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2+2x+4$?

Comment: Can give me.more please? In coordinates i believe is easier, just i look who is above and look the intersection. Please?

Comment: You found the curves intersect at $\theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$. Naturally limits of integration are from $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{3}$ to $\theta = +\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is important to have an accurate drawing (using free software like Geogebra or Desmos) :

[image]

Then, as you would do for the difference of two areas between curves having a cartesian equation, your area is :

$$A=\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(3\cos\theta)^2d\theta -  \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(1+\cos\theta)^2d\theta \right)$$

Compared with your formula, the bounds are not the same, there is a minus sign and an exchange of functions : "largest swept area (by red curve) minus smallest swept area" (by green curve)".

Due to symmetry $\theta \leftrightarrow -\theta$, $A$ can be written :

$$A=2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(3\cos\theta)^2d\theta -  \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(1+\cos\theta)^2d\theta \right)$$

$$A=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left((3\cos\theta)^2-(1+\cos\theta)^2\right)d\theta$$

you will find $A=\pi$ (crescent area)

Now, if you want the area $B$ instead (and I understand now that it is that your question), just consider that we have the equality :

$$A+B=\pi (3/2)^2$$

(area of a disk with radius $3/2$), from which we can deduce

$$B=5\pi/4$$

Comment: thank you. So, always in polar coordinates only need look who is greater in size (above) minus least(below)?My confusion was because i have some graph more in left than another one.

Comment: The principle is "outside minus inside" in this case.

Comment: @SeanRoberson thank you so much

Comment: The integral for me was $\pi$, is ok @Jean Marie? Thank you

Comment: That's right !...

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @JeanMarie Excuse me, i found a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519906/find-the-area-inside-r-3-cos-theta-and-outside-r-1-cos-theta.  Is coincidence that the area is the same? I am confused, thank you

Comment: Same question also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625921/305862)

Comment: @JeanMarie, i am stupid sorry. The area that i need to calculated is not that, i want the area inside of the green curve but inside the red curve too, sorry for that, how can do that? thank you

Comment: I am realizing that I have interpreted in a certain way your question. I have re-written my answer and modified the figure. I apologize for this initial confusion.

Comment: @JeanMarie very clear, thank you so much!!!